# Populate two column grid with databinding?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do i populate a two column grid with objects from my observable collection?

I've tried to achieve this effect by using the tookits wrap panel but the items just stack.

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="400">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Trips}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="236" Width="182">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikButtonTrip}">
                        <StackPanel Width="152" Height="140">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FromName}" />
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="till" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToName}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" FontSize="16" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" Text="{Binding TravelTimeText}" />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" Margin="0,-6,0,0" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding TransferCountText}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only child for the `WrapPanel` will be the `ItemsControl` so the stacking is done by the internal `ItemsPanel` in the `ItemsControl` which, by default, is a `StackPanel` with Vertical Orientation. So to get "two columns", try to move the `WrapPanel` into the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` instead like this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Trips}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="400"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Height="236" Width="182">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource VasttrafikButtonTrip}">
                    <StackPanel Width="152" Height="140">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FromName}" />
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="till" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" FontSize="16" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" Text="{Binding TravelTimeText}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" Margin="0,-6,0,0" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding TransferCountText}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```